# celery beat doesn't work properly

Tags: celery, django-celery, celerybeat

when i run this command for celery beat.

> [2013-06-27 02:17:05,936: INFO/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Starting...
>
> [2013-06-27 02:17:05,937: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
>
> [2013-06-27 02:17:08,711: INFO/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed.
>
> [2013-06-27 02:17:08,712: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...

it is stuck on this result. but in my settings.py I have configured the CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE.

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"

from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
    'task': 'celerytest.tasks.add',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
    'args': (16, 16)
    },

    'add-every-10-seconds': {
    'task': 'celerytest.tasks.minus',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=10),
    'args': (20, 16)
    },

}
```

What's wrong with my celery beat?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `celery beat` command starts the [celery scheduler](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler). This process schedules tasks  and places them in a queue periodically. It does not execute tasks.

You need to start `celery beat` **and** `celery worker` (I guess you are using django-celery):

```
python manage.py celery beat
python manage.py celery worker
```

Or simply:

```
python manage.py celery worker --beat
```

Comment: why is it that the celery beat keeps on sending tasks even if it's only set to `@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(day_of_month='1'))` ?

Comment: if you are using DatabaseScheduler, you need to cleanup your database, otherwise you can delete `celerybeat-schedule` file

Comment: thanks! btw, can I use celery periodic task in backing up my database?

Comment: @user2357067, yes, you can. But don't you think, that `cron + bash script` is much easier?

Comment: I have no idea because I haven't tried both. Do you suggest that it is better and easier to use `cron + bash script`?

Comment: After long time I congratulate myself, it is work fine :)) Thank you